# Intrinsic spin in a rotating frame of reference? Thought experiment get me confused, how to deal with this paradox?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, reference-frames, quantum-spin

Consider a ring of stationary electrons fixed in a circle on the x-y plane around the z-axis, and an electron above the circle on the z-axis. That lone electron can have spin pointing either up or down the z-axis. Now by Coulomb force the lone electrons will be pushed up the z-axis.

But now consider a rotating frame of reference where the z-axis is fixed but the new x-y plane is rotating at some velocity w around the origin. In this frame of reference, the electrons are moving around the circle with velocity w, so it creates a magnetic field. This act on the lone electron because of its magnetic moment. The total force caused by this is dependent on total current, and hence w, and the spin of the electron. However, since intrinsic spin is quantized, it cannot be different between different reference frame, so it's independent of w, and it can only take on 2 values for 2 directions, depends on which spin we chose in the beginning.

But because different frame of reference must predict the same final result, the electrons must still be moving up with the same acceleration. That means Coulomb force in this frame of reference must be altered to match. But because the magnetic force depends on the direction of intrinsic spin, Coulomb force must be dependent on intrinsic spin as well. But this sounds very wrong.

So is this conclusion correct? Intrinsic spin are independent on **all** frame of reference, and Coulomb force is dependent on intrinsic spin. Or am I wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The paradox can be resolved by noting that Maxwell's equations are not invariant under a change into a non-inertial reference frame.

More specifically, you can't expect the usual formula for how a current creates a magnetic field to work in a rotating frame.

Comment: But that just push the issue back. Since Maxwell's equations are confirmed by experiments done on Earth, which is rotating and spinning, it should work even if we don't know whether our reference frame is inertia or not. Unless this also means to say Maxwell's equations also don't work for, say, people on ISSS because they are in acceleration compared to Earth.

Comment: Maxwells equations, just as newtons second law, are approximately true if the reference frame is approximately inertial.

Comment: So which frame is the inertia frame? And I'm still confused because this still give the result that you can't tell that a magnetic force exist just from current, either that or Coulomb force is dependent on intrinsic spin, without knowing which frame you're in.